# CSS url() format() - what does it do?

Tags: css, url, fonts, font-face

I am having trouble finding any documentation about the following CSS syntax, mainly because any page about 'css url format' is talking about the way URL's are structured, and not this particular syntax:

```
@font-face{
font-family:awesomefont;
src: url(fonts/awesome.woff) format("woff"),
url(fonts/awesome.ttf) format("truetype")
}
```

What does the **format()** part do here? I guess it tells the browsers what type of file they should expect. However, I have not seen it anywhere else except in @font-face declarations, but does it get used outside of that as well?

And how does the 'format'  relate to the MIME type of the requested file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [CSS3 Fonts module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc):

> External references consist of a URL, followed by an optional hint describing the format of the font resource referenced by that URL. The format hint contains a comma-separated list of format strings that denote well-known font formats. Conformant user agents must skip downloading a font resource if the format hints indicate only unsupported or unknown font formats. If no format hints are supplied, the user agent should download the font resource.

The specification makes no mention of MIME types, however.

The `format()` syntax only appears in the `@font-face` rule.

Answer (score 1):

> Because there are no defined MIME types for TrueType, OpenType, and
>   Web Open File Format (WOFF) fonts, the MIME type of the file specified
>   is not considered.

Learn more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face